# How to track window open url

Tags: javascript

I am doing this

```
<button id="gbs" class="btn btn-standard" style="margin-top:5px;margin-left:20px;" onclick="window.open('https://example.com/#appraisal')">
  Create Appraisal
</button>
```

When I try to get the URL from open event with `document.referrer` I get the original page url:

```
https://example.com/api/ACinvoices.php?invoices=915212&print=1&customer=21402
```

Attaching image to understand me better:

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6669620/519413

Comment: What do you mean by "track"?